# UIBackgroundMode location works only for three minutes on iOS 7

Tags: ios

I have implemented following in my `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

It will work for three minutes in background and after three minutes `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` will run, How can i make it work for longer?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"ending background task");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];



NSTimer *timerlocation = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
                                                  target:locationManager
                              selector:@selector(startUpdatingLocation)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
```

}

Comment: You don't. That's all you get using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

Comment: There is a specific background mode for receiving location updates - Refer to the core location programming guide

Comment: @rmaddy so are you saying even by implementing UIBackgroundModes,we just get three minutes in background???

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what i am doing, but still getting just three minutes.

Comment: Once you have background modes enabled for location, you don't need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` - you just get calls to your CLLocationDelegate.  In your delegate methods you should only do a minimum amount of work (a few seconds at most).  If you want to do more then you can begin a background task, but you will still only get 3 minutes - but that should be plenty of time to perform most background update tasks

Comment: @aasma No, I'm saying that using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` alone only gets you 3 minutes. You don't use that for handling background location updates.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the background mode for "receiving location updates." Then if you call `startUpdatingLocation` while the app is in the foreground, it will continue to check the location in the background.

Comment: Are you trying to get location every N minutes in the background? In that case, the maximum limit is 3 minutes but it's tricky to make sure the OS doesn't kill the app when in background.